# Scheduling Posts to Feeds with Meta Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, scheduling

I am trying to use the Meta Graph API to schedule contents with attachments on my feeds but scheduling with the object_attachment parameter doesn't work, instead, it posts the contents immediately after the execution. However, posts without the object_attachment field schedules properly.

I'd love to know if something is not being properly included or how to make it work as expected.

My Code:

```
const axios = require("axios");

const apiUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/101253..../feed";
const accessToken = "EAATyfKiPHeQBO3H....";

const futureDate = new Date("August 29, 2023 18:00:00").getTime() / 1000;
const requestData = {
  access_token: accessToken,
  published: false,
  scheduled_publish_time: futureDate,
  message: 'message to be scheduled',
  object_attachment: "294925976.....",
};

axios
  .post(apiUrl, requestData)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Response:", response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```